# Android Publisher API - get extra data (detect which user made purchase)

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api

For in-app subscription I'm using this code (in Kotlin)

```
iabHelper.launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow(act, "month", 1001, this@SubscriptionActivity, extraKey)
```

After this I'm making request to server for purchase verifying. For verification on server I'm using this code (in Go)

```
result, err := androidpublisher.Purchases.Subscriptions.Get(packageName, product, token).Do()
success := err == nil
```

How to get extraKey which I passed in app? I need it to know, which user made purchase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused by parameter name "extraData", and was looking for same field in request result.
But when I looked at the IabHelper source, I found this

> @param extraData Extra data (developer payload), which will be
>   returned with the purchase
>        *      data when the purchase completes. This extra data will be permanently bound to that
>        *      purchase and will always be returned when the purchase is queried

So, extra data is in DeveloperPayload field

```
result, err := publ.Purchases.Subscriptions.Get(packageName, product, token).Do()
success := err == nil && result.DeveloperPayload == extraKey
```

Also, note, which can be useful for those, who aren't reading [docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html)

> Note: Do not use the user's email address in the payload string, since that address may change.